# Solve this integral by hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I was trying to find the normalization constant of the following distribution:$$p(x)=(1-(1-q)x^2)^{\frac{1}{1 - q}}$$ where $1<q<3$, which done by integration over $p(x)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ as $$A=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}p(x)dx=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}(1-(1-q)x^2)^{\frac{1}{1 - q}}dx$$ which according to Wolfram Mathematica $A=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(\frac{1}{q-1}-\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{q-1} \Gamma(\frac{1}{q-1})}$, I believe such integration can be calculated by hypergeometrical functions, but I don't know how, I would be glad if someone give me a help to find a way to know how to solve such integral?

I also wonder, can such integral be solved by hypergeometric functions
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}(1-(1-q)x^2)^{\frac{1}{1 - q}}(1-(1-q)(x+c)^2)^{\frac{1}{1 - q}}dx$$ my question emerges from the fact that the integrand is not an even function, if not, what other methods can be used

Thanks in advance

Comment: If we take $1 + (q - 1) x^2 = 1/u$ in the first integral, we get $\int_0^1 u^a (1 - u)^b du$, which is one of the definitions of the beta function. The second integral is
$$\sqrt r \hspace {1.5 px}
 B {\left( \frac 1 2, 2 r - \frac 1 2 \right)} \hspace {1.5 px}
 {_2 F_1} {\left(
  r, 2 r - \frac 1 2; r + \frac 1 2;
  -\frac {c^2} {4 r} \right)},$$
where $r = 1/(q - 1)$.

Comment: @Maxim. Please, write an answer.

Comment: @Maxim. Thank you very much, it is useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, the antiderivative express in terms of the gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I=\int\Big[1-(1-q)x^2)\Big]^{\frac{1}{1 - q}}\,dx=x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{q-1};\frac{3}{2};(1-q) x^2\right)$$ and the definite integral
$$J=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Big[1-(1-q)x^2)\Big]^{\frac{1}{1 - q}}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{q-1}}\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3-q}{2 (q-1)}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{q-1}\right)}$$ provided that
$$2 \Re\left(\frac{q-2}{q-1}\right)<1\land (\Re(q)\geq 1\lor q\notin \mathbb{R})$$ which is your case with $1<q<3$.

For the second integral, I do not see any possible solution except a series expansion around $c=0$.

For simplicity, let $a=q-1$ and b=$\frac 1 {1-q}$ to make
$$K=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(1+a x^2\right)^b \left(1+a (x+c)^2\right)^b\,dx$$

using
$$\left(1+a (x+c)^2\right)^{b}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty Q_n\, c^n$$

$$K=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c^n\,K_n \quad \text{where}\quad K_n=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(1+a x^2\right)^b \,Q_n\,dx$$

We have $K_{2n+1}=0$ and
$$K_{2n}=(-1)^{\frac n2} a^{\frac {n-1}2}\sqrt \pi\ \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n-1}{2}-2 b\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)
   \Gamma (n-2 b)}\, \prod_{k=0}^{\frac n2 -1}(b-k)^2$$

This means that $K$ is again an hypergoemetric function. I shall not write it since @Maxim gave the complete result (much more simpler than mine).

Comment: Thanks for the details, I think now it is clear to me, please would you recommend any textbook that helps me to master Hypergeometric functions?